# Find the Q-factor for coils and understand weak power transfer

Tags: inductance, resonance, coupling, wireless-charging

I built coils for wireless power transfer. Found inductance with a LRC meter. Put capacitors, hoping for a resonant frequency at 300kHz. Student assisted me with a NVA machine where a resonant frequency 800kHz was found. It plots power transfer over frequency. My capacitor values were pretty off. Needed a .9micro farad and used a 1micro farad. Still a large shift from 300 to 800kHz. It had like 80% transfer over 2cm distance.[image] The yellow line is S21 at 800kHz.

I also purchased wurht coils https://www.we-online.de/katalog/datasheet/760308111.pdf. Saw a high Q factor around 200-300kHz. Placed capacitors for 270kHz resonance. And they worked best at 303kHz. It lit an led from centimeters away!. [image]

When I place a led on my coil design it doesn't light at all. My coils show power transfer on the NVA machine yet can't light up a led. Wurth coils work great wirelessly lighting up a led.

Could it be the Q facotr? Never payed attention to Q until I bought the wurth coils which inside their data sheet show high Q as a function of frequency.

Looked up the equitation for Q and got Q series = 2 pi f L / R. This graph should look liner with frequency. The Q data graph [image] looks more complicated(maybe R changes with f). I'm lost. Why don't my coils light up a led, even with them almost touching(NVA says 95 power transfer). Also how would I calculate Q and better understand Q for my coils. I believe either the NVA machine was wrong or my S21 has a power sent so week, that my coils could not light a led. Maybe if I run my design at resonance and high Q value. Any tips or resources would help.

Comment: If you have finished with this question you should mark the answer as "accepted" as per [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png). This tells other people that the chosen answer is reliable.

Answer (score 2):

> *Any tips or resources would help.*

The [Wurth coil](https://uk.farnell.com/wurth-elektronik/760308111/coil-6-3uh-13a-10-wireless-charging/dp/2291720) as sold by Farnell: -

[image]

What do you think that the black support sheet is made from?

Answer - it's partially made of ferrite material and, it will highly concentrate the fields from your transmit coil and collect more energy in effect. If you want to prove this, get a magnet and feel the attraction force. It should be maximized at around the centre of the plate i.e. the ferrite is probably a disc placed centrally to attract the AC magnetic fields through the centre of the coil arrangement. You want magnetic flux to be drawn through the centre.

Here's what Farnell say about this coil: -

> *The 760308111 is a wireless power charging Transmitter Coil with pot
> core results in limiting the stray field in the design. This WE-WPCC
> coil features high permeability shielding coil*

It's not great or perfect language but, I think you can see that it uses ferrite material to enhance the ability of the basic coil. The data sheet also says this: -

> *Direct mechanical impact to the product shall be prevented as the
> ferrite material of the core could flake or in the worst case it could
> break*

Notice the words core and ferrite!

Your coil (this one): -

[image]

It has no ferrite material to enhance its ability to collect energy - that's your first problem and it's a show-stopper in my opinion. Of course, if your receive coil and transmit coil were equal size then it's less of a problem.

The second problem is that it only has 3 turns and is therefore not resonant at the same low frequency compared to the Wurth coil.

If you then made your transmit coil resonant at the higher frequency (to make it compatible with the resonant frequency of **your** homespun receive coil), there will be less current in the transmit coil because its impedance will be higher. Therefore less energy transferred. OK, if you are series resonating the transmit coil this may be less of a problem.

Given that this type of arrangement is a transformer, having fewer turns on the secondary also means less voltage produced by the receive coil.

In all of these types of experiment, you should be prepared to re-tune with capacitance and tweak the driving frequency and keep checking this. You only really need to look for voltage amplitude on the output coil so trying to measure S parameters is missing the direct point. Use a signal generator and use an oscilloscope to set it up, then use your other equipment to make precise measurements.

I might add that in all the power transfer coils I've built I only ever used a signal generator and oscilloscope and I got great results and built probably about ten systems for customers that are still in use today.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know ferrite on my tx or rx could help. I’ve seen videos with no ferrite, small rx and it can light up a led. My rx is small, three turns, and very thin. The oscilloscope is a great tip. Main questions are do I need to worry about Q? Why does a NVA machine show me 90+% efficiency at 800kHz so with a function generator at 10 volts amplitude and 800kHz, my coils can’t light up a led.(maybe the oscilloscope will tell) Last, I measured L on both tx and rx, found capacitors that should resonate at 300kHz, yet NVA shows high S21 at 800kHz, why such a big shift?

Comment: I have no idea about your test equipment. Go back to basics is my certain and strong advice.

Comment: Is there potential for my small rx to light up a led?

Comment: You might need more turns but, I would advise you to get some ferrite material and be prepared to increase the number of turns on your receive coil. You have the facts in front of you - the Wurth device works and your homespun one doesn't.

Comment: Yes I’m going back to basics. I’m gonna try them at a higher frequency too. Thank you

Comment: If you research MPT you will find this can be done where the gap can transfer power almost up to coil diameter over 11kW in 3rd Gen devices.  However your load must match the transferred impedance exactly and then you only get 50% efficiency at MPT.  With reduced load, greater efficiency. So choosing resonant frequency must also factor impedance of √(L/C)=Zo then mutual coupling L dominates the equation.

Comment: But since M mutual inductance coupling is weak, It is better to use step-up autotransformer coil for Tx and inverse step down coil for Rx to allow higher L and low C high Z mutual impedance and thus higher E field.  Then consider Q to reduce when targeting for MPPT load including high Zo of the mutual coupling.  So compute impedances of your WPT coil design for each stage.  Then you will see quantum leaps in power transfer. But many more turns are needed.

Comment: I am fairly naive. I saw a YouTube clip where someone build coils in ANSYS. Found their L. Then found C at whatever frequency so that c = 1/4pi^2 f L. With both caps on and same frequency in the kHz range, wpt simulations where great. Had my coils built got caps and no led even lit. Should be similar design to https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=l8Y7L2eT8WE . I know a little of rf, but thought impedance, mutual inductance, impedance matching was for high MHz and GHz so I thought there was low f circuit and high f circuit.

Comment: Appreciate what you said and will look into it

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I think you are incorrect by telling the OP that many more turns are required. The optimum transmit coil will be a single turn that is highly resonant and ditto the receive coil but, of course it isn't always practical with such low reactances unless you are bumping up the frequency. In the mid hundreds of kHz, single turn transmit coils are used in food metal detectors (circa 1 uH) and experts in that field (and I count myself as one) will use parallel transmit coils to reduce inductance on large machines.....

Comment: .... @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 As for coupling energy to rotating machines (which I also count myself as an expert on), the best results for transmitting power in the mid 100 kHz is also to limit the turns to around 1 uH to 10 uH. Been there; bought the T-shirt.

Comment: Andy aka can you please tell me where my design differed from the YouTube video I posted. The theory is about half way in the video. He has large single loop. I thought I could apply his design to my smaller coils since I’ve seen smaller coils built ( Wurth) and at least light up a led

Comment: I only saw two transmit windings (as per what I said to Tony about keeping the number of turns down) - your transmit coil has 10 or more turns and inductance rises with turns squared hence, the inductance will be high and it needs much more voltage to get current flowing. You'll also get far better results with ceramic capacitors rather than polyester. The better the dielectric (NP0 is the best), the more resonance you get and the more transmit current you get. It didn't cover what operating frequency it used so I can't add much more.

Comment: Ok great! My tx had inductance 16.8 micro H. So smaller L is better because less voltage needed ? So if I were to fabricate a large two winding tx and a smaller two winding rx you could expect better results? I just purchased a case of Mylar caps :| to help me build my own coils.

Comment: Is it literally from the equation i(t) = 1/L integral v(t)dt ? So larger the L, smaller the current. Is that my issue, is that my tx is choking my current?

Comment: Try to aim for about 1 or 2 uH is my advice. I'm sure there are some on-line calculators that will give you theoretical numbers. Higher inductance means a higher drive voltage.

Comment: My tx is 16.5 micro H. The Wurth came out to 7 micro H. Maybe the Wurth overcome their inductance with ferrite and better design? I’m going to try what you said. Thank you

Comment: Remember the ferrite in the Wurth coil "draws in" much more flux than your receive coil. Anyway, we have to draw this discussion to a conclusion because we'll get told off for extended comments.

Comment: @Andyaka my initial experience was with my LED client who use WPT to power 20 LEDs with 20mA thru the concrete or asphalt for road studs and I proved to them how to improve efficiency with gap= coil diam. Using what I described.  They were using high Q resonant ferrite bars, I used 1 turn to make the autotransformer for the Rx and that improved the gap to power the Stud. (Injection plastic flying saucer roadside illumination)

Comment: Using the Rx Coil as an autotransformer does a better job of impedance matching with low Rs LED’s in a series string 10S2P. And using a Ferrite bar increases the inductance greatly . I also supplied Polyurethane Caps binned in 1% values from my RLC tester for high Q.  That was over 13 yrs ago in NZ.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111606/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-aka-find-the-q-factor-for-coils-and-understand-weak).

Comment: @VoltageSpike yes please do move to chat - shouldn't you have deleted all but say the first two comments?